# Storing searchable JSon in MySql

Tags: mysql, json, solr, nosql

I have a following table :

```
id | notification_id | user_id | metadata | created_at | modified_at
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                 |         |          |            |
```

the field **metadata** contains a json object such as :

```
{"transferId":100010003,
 "timestamp":1401778800000,
 "amount":1150,
 "customerTimestamp":1401778800000,
 "customerFullName":"John cusack",
 "customerMsisdn":460100000003,
 "customerMessage":"Test payment3",
 "assignee":Bob,
 "comments":this is a comment,
 "currency":"SEK",
 "balanced":false,
 "inboxNotificationId":0}
```

The above json is searchable. Meaning there might be a request for transaction metadata where customerName = john cusack and user_id = 1234.

I totally understand that this is a very bad design. NEVER store a json object in RDBMS if it's prone to change or it will be searched on.

I want to optimise the schema so that when I query the data, it does not take a lot of time to return me the results(which currently it takes a lot of time). For this I can think of three options :

- Breakup the json object and store the fields in seperate columns and
  index them.
- Use NoSql DB like MongoDB for storing json
- Use solr

Which one is the most logical and beneficial? all of them? May someone please stress specially on solr (since i dont know how it works), regarding why I should or should not use it?

Cheers!!

Comment: Consider decoding it prior to storage, and store separately in a normalised environment.

Comment: You mean the first point i made? (Breakup the json object and store the fields in seperate columns and index them.)

Comment: Yes. Exactly! (But I'm biased)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely want to flat the JSON into the individual fields. You have different types in there (strings, booleans, numbers, etc) and you want them processed separately. Then you can decide what you do, but you certainly can do use Solr for this kind of things.